# Unity Rigidbody

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am new to unity and trying to make the player jump on start.
I have the following code

```
using System.Collections;
using UnityEngine;

public class playermove : MonoBehaviour
{
    public float Force = 20f;
    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        Rigidbody.AddForce(0f, 0f, 200f);
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
    }
}
```

Its throwing me the following error

```
Assets\playermove.cs(10,9): error CS0120: An object reference is required for the non-static field, method, or property 'Rigidbody.AddForce(float, float, float)'
```

Comment: Please use the correct tags! Just because you are using a certain IDE doesn't mean your question is actually about that IDE. And please be aware that `unityscript` is or better **was** a JavaScript flavor like custom language used in early Unity versions and is long **deprecated** by now. Your code is of course in `c#`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need an instance of class Rigidbody

```
using System.Collections;
using UnityEngine;

[RequireComponent(typeof(Rigidbody))]
public class playermove : MonoBehaviour
{
public Rigidbody rb;
public float Force = 20f;
// Start is called before the first frame update
void Start()
{
    rb = GetComponent<Rigidbody>();
    rb.AddForce(0f, 0f, Force);
}

// Update is called once per frame
void Update()
{
}
}
```

Comment: @derHugo I didn't knew that unityscript is a deprecated language. I thought that it is related to scripting in Unity. I am sorry.